# How to create a simple Kripke model in NuSMV?

Tags: logic, ctl, nusmv

I am currently doing some theoretical research in LTL (Linear-time Temporal Logic) and CTL (Computation Tree Logic). I am new to NuSMV and I have difficulty to create a simple Kripke structure.

My structure is M = (S, R, L) where S = {s0, s1, s2} is the set of possible states, R is a transition relation such that: s0 -> s1, s0 -> s2, s1 -> s0, s1 -> s2, and s2 -> s2, and L is the labeling function for each state defined by: L(s0) = {p, q}, L(s1) = {q, r}, and L(s2) = {r}. I am using notations describe in Logic in Computer Science textbook by Huth and Ryan. I have tried two following codes:

The first code:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    p : boolean;
    q : boolean;
    r : boolean;
    state : {s0, s1, s2};

ASSIGN
    init(state) := s0;
    next(state) := 
        case
            state = s0          : {s1, s2};
            state = s1          : {s2};
            state = s2          : {s2};
        esac;

    init(p) := TRUE; 
    init(q) := TRUE;
    init(r) := FALSE;

    next(p) :=
        case
            state = s1 | state = s2     : FALSE;
        esac;
    next(q) :=
        case
            state = s1                  : TRUE;
            state = s2                  : FALSE;
        esac;
    next(r) :=
        case
            state = s1                  : FALSE;
            state = s2                  : TRUE;
        esac;

SPEC
    p & q
```

The second code:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    p : boolean;
    q : boolean;
    r : boolean;
    state : {s0, s1, s2};

ASSIGN
    init(state) := s0;
    next(state) := 
        case
            state = s0          : {s1, s2};
            state = s1          : {s2};
            state = s2          : {s2};
        esac;

    init(p) := TRUE; 
    init(q) := TRUE;
    init(r) := FALSE;

    next(p) := !p;
    next(q) :=
        case
            state = s0 & next(state) = s1   : q;
            state = s0 & next(state) = s2   : !q;
            state = s1 & next(state) = s0   : q;
            state = s1 & next(state) = s2   : !q;
        esac;
    next(r) :=
        case
            state = s0 & next(state) = s1   : r;
            state = s0 & next(state) = s2   : r;
            state = s1 & next(state) = s0   : !r;
            state = s1 & next(state) = s2   : r;
        esac;

LTLSPEC
    p & q
```

Something was wrong and I got this message: "case conditions are not exhaustive". What does it mean? How do I fix my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you must enter for each case also its "default".
The first code:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    p : boolean;
    q : boolean;
    r : boolean;
    state : {s0, s1, s2};

ASSIGN
    init(state) := s0;
    next(state) := 
    case
        state = s0          : {s1, s2};
        state = s1          : {s2};
        state = s2          : {s2};
        TRUE                : state;
    esac;

   init(p) := TRUE; 
   init(q) := TRUE;
   init(r) := FALSE;

   next(p) :=
    case
        state = s1 | state = s2     : FALSE;
    esac;
   next(q) :=
    case
        state = s1                  : TRUE;
        state = s2                  : FALSE;
        TRUE                        : q;
    esac;
   next(r) :=
    case
        state = s1                  : FALSE;
        state = s2                  : TRUE;
        TRUE                        : r;
    esac;

SPEC
    p & q
```

and the second code:

```
MODULE main
VAR
p : boolean;
q : boolean;
r : boolean;
state : {s0, s1, s2};

ASSIGN
init(state) := s0;
next(state) := 
    case
        state = s0          : {s1, s2};
        state = s1          : {s2};
        state = s2          : {s2};
        TRUE                : state;
    esac;

init(p) := TRUE; 
init(q) := TRUE;
init(r) := FALSE;

next(p) := !p;
next(q) :=
    case
        state = s0 & next(state) = s1   : q;
        state = s0 & next(state) = s2   : !q;
        state = s1 & next(state) = s0   : q;
        state = s1 & next(state) = s2   : !q;
        TRUE                            : q;
    esac;
next(r) :=
    case
        state = s0 & next(state) = s1   : r;
        state = s0 & next(state) = s2   : r;
        state = s1 & next(state) = s0   : !r;
        state = s1 & next(state) = s2   : r;
        TRUE                            : r;
    esac;

LTLSPEC
    p & q
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that you fixed my codes by add following scripts: **TRUE : state**, **TRUE : p**, **TRUE : q**, and **TRUE : r**. Can you explain to me what do these scripts mean? I know that for an atomic proposition x (or a set of atomic propositions), the script **x : TRUE** means assigning the truth value TRUE to x (or every element in x). This is the first time I see the inverses (e.g. **TRUE : x**).

Comment: if you programming in any languages the switch case have a "default" case. The default case is true if any other cases aren't true and this case for NuSMV is necessary. In next(r) if the first four cases are false the last case (TRUE) is TRUE then next(r) := r; Do you understand? Please check my last question.. i need it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428769/convert-ctl-formula-in-ltl-and-ctl