# how to create a structure of kripke in NuSMV?

Tags: model-checking

i must to create a structure of Kripke in NuSMV and i must to check some properties.

Anybody help me? The structure and the properties(LTL, CTL and CTL*) are in the pictures.

Here there is a structure and properties:

http://cl.ly/image/1x0b1v3E0P0D/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-16%20at%2016.52.34.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simpler and seemingly more reliable NuSMV code for your Kripke Structure. Thanks to [dejvuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547337/dejvuth) for his answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012308/bug-in-nusmv-model-checking/34026713#34026713). The code is as follows

```
     MODULE main
     VAR
        state : {s0,s1,s2,s3,s4};
     ASSIGN
        init(state) := s0;
        next(state):=
             case
                 state = s0 : {s1,s2};
                 state = s1 : {s1,s2};
                 state = s2 : {s1,s2,s3};
                 state = s3 : {s1,s4};
                 state = s4 : {s4};
             esac;
     DEFINE
        p := state = s1 | state = s2 | state = s3 | state = s4;
        q := state = s1 | state = s2;
        r := state = s3;
     SPEC
       EG p;
     SPEC
       AG p;
     SPEC
       EF (AG p);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know NuSMV only handles LTL and CTL formulas (see [NuSMV in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuSMV)). The formulas in problem 1-3 are CTL formulas, hence it can be model-checked by NuSMV. However the formulas in problem 4 & 5 are CTL* formulas, and thus *we cannot straightforwardly use them as an input to NuSMV*. You also need to understand that the **set of all CTL* formulas is the proper superset of the union of all LTL and CTL formulas**. This conditions implies that some CTL* formulas do not have their equivalent LTL or CTL formulas (see [CTL* in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTL*)). Your Kripke structure can be defined in NuSMV by following code:

```
MODULE main

VAR
    p       : boolean;
    q       : boolean;
    r       : boolean;
    state   : {s0,s1,s2,s3,s4};

ASSIGN
    init (state)    := s0;
    next (state)    :=
    case
        state = s0          : {s1, s2};
        state = s1          : {s1, s2};
        state = s2          : {s1, s2, s3};
        state = s3          : {s1, s4};
        state = s4          : {s4};
        TRUE                : state;
    esac;

    init (p) := FALSE;
    init (q) := FALSE;
    init (r) := FALSE;

    next(p) :=
        case 
            state = s1 | state = s2 | state = s3 | state = s4       : TRUE;
            TRUE                                                    : p;
        esac;
    next(q) :=
        case
            state = s1 | state = s2                                 : TRUE;
            state = s3 | state = s4                                 : FALSE;
            TRUE                                                    : q;
        esac;
    next(r) :=
        case
            state = s3                                              : TRUE;
            state = s1 | state = s2 | state = s4                    : FALSE;
            TRUE                                                    : r;
        esac;
SPEC
    EG p;
SPEC
    AG p;
SPEC
    EF (AG p);
```

Of course, there is another way to define your Kripke structure in NuSMV, but I think this is one of the easiest. (Anyway, thanks for helping me with [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884125/how-to-create-a-simple-kripke-model-in-nusmv)).

As for the formulas in problem 4 & 5, here is my answer.

The formula **AF [p U EG ( p -> q)]** is of the form **AF [\phi]**, where **\phi** is an LTL formula **p U EG (p->q)**. Since the LTL formula **\phi** is satisfied in a Kripke model if for every path starting at s0 we have the satisfaction of **\phi**, then we translate **AF [p U EG ( p -> q)]** into **AF A[p U EG ( p -> q)]**.

By similar argument, we translate **EG[(( p & q ) | r) U ( r U AG p)]** into **EG[A(( p & q ) | r) U A( r U AG p)]**.

Comment: Thank you so much! You save me and my exam! I have some problem to write this formula EG[A(( p & q ) | r) U A( r U AG p)] because NuSMV find some parse error, but is't a problem! I also have to do the three versions of dekker in NuSMV .. I hate these things!Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course NuSMV yields parser error for such formula. As I said previously, the formula EG[(( p & q ) | r) U ( r U AG p)] is a CTL* formula. Although some CTL* formulas can be translated to CTL using the path quantifier A or E, I suggest you to check the semantics mathematically (i.e. using pencil and papers). I recommend the textbook by Huth and Ryan (http://books.google.com/books/about/Logic_in_Computer_Science.html?id=zAchdqsWkL0C&redir_esc=y).

Comment: ok, thanks! I have one last question.. please save me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525051/check-deadlock-starvation-freeness-in-dekker-with-ctl-formula